# WCF: Configure roles to access database resources

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, authorization

I have a WCF service set up on the web server. This service, when accessed, does some database operations. What sort of account (roles and permissions) should this WCF service have to interact with the data base and how the same can be created. Is network service the way to achieve this?

This service will be accessed by vast group of users and these users will be having varying levels of restriction. How should i go about implementing this in a most secure and robust manner??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use certificate . http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28248/Securing-WCF-Services-with-Certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this depends on many factors.

You have to first answer at least those two questions:

- who is responsible of authentication: your active directory (user valid against AD), the database (SQL Server user), or do you use a custom authentication system (`User` table in your DB)?
- who is responsible of authorization: your active directory (user group), the database (SQL Server roles), or do you use a custom authentication system (`Role`, `UserRole` tables)?

When you answer those questions, that are related to the way you want to manage security (not *how* to actually implement this with WCF), *then* you can find a way using WCF.

More specifically, you'll have to choose the WCF security configuration for authentication:

Message vs Transport security

- `Windows` (great to integrate your application in an AD)
- `Username` (login + password)
- ...etc.

Then a role-based authorization provider, if any:

- `SqlRoleProvider` (SQL Server roles)
- Windows groups (for Windows domains)
- custom
- etc.

So you have to make some choices first, then I recommend you to read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx) to choose the security configuration to use, depending on how you expect managing authentication and authorization.